# Absolutely positioned div containing a child div with overflow hidden which contains 2 divs, one fixed height and one scrolling

Tags: html, css

A web app has the following structure but the scroll goes off the page. Any ideas what is going wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/kYEES/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed-height">
    <p>Fixed height div</p>
  </div>

  <div class="scrolling-height">
    <p>Scrolling div</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper { 
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  background: lightgray;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative; 
}

.fixed-height {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.scrolling-height {
  background-color: green;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Something wrong with http://jsfiddle.net/DhWm5/1/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DhWm5/3/
I gave your container a `position: relative` and your scrollable `div` an absolute position:

```
.container {
    background: lightgray;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    position:relative;
}
.scrolling-height {
    background-color: green;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50px; bottom: 0;
}
```

The `top: 50px` is to allow for the fixed height `div` and its padding;

Comment: Ok, this works, great. Is there a way without absolute positioning? Just curious.

Comment: Not unless you always know the height of your container div or using jQuery. At least as far as I know ;) Any reason why you don't want absolute positioning?

Comment: No, not really, just sometimes feels a bit hacky.

Comment: It can be very powerful if used correctly. Perfectly acceptable to use. I'd recommend reading the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275084/why-shouldnt-i-use-positionabsolute-for-positioning-everything

Comment: The solution doesn't work if it's in an external wrapper that is set to position absolute. I've realised, after working through your solution, that it's this aspect that is the actual problem. Check this update http://jsfiddle.net/ADR8K/

Comment: You need to give `.container` a position other than static or else `.scrolling-height` won't be positioned absolutely to it, it'll be positioned according to the next parent element with a non-static `position` http://jsfiddle.net/ADR8K/1/

Comment: Even with positon relative the scroll goes off the page, which was my original problem http://jsfiddle.net/kYEES/